# Conditional formatting to highlight difference of two numbers bigger than a specified value

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to do a conditional formatting that highlights month-over-month difference that is bigger than 1%

If (Sep - Aug) > 1%, then highlight it

Sharing the sheet below and showing what I want the conditional formatting to do below:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qDobIRB_PUpW1MI7gg5BgsV6zNLcCWlc0T41KyQXz_o/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Under 'Format', there is "Conditional Formatting". Just apply the logic to color those cells with the value that you specified (1%)

Comment: sheet is private. also add more details of what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

In Format > Conditional Formatting you can set a custom formula:
[image]

```
=ABS(C6- B6)>1%
```

ABS returns the absolute value of the difference, so you'll be considering positive and negative differences bigger than 1%